# A node not being typeset

Tags: tikz-pgf

I draw an angle of 30 degrees at the origin. The common endpoint of the two line segments comprising this angle is `D` and the other endpoints are `E` and `F`.  I draw a dashed circular arc about `F`.  I want to use the command

`\draw[dashed,draw=blue!30] (F) -- (F) ++(225:3.75) node [midway,above left]{$5$};`

to label the radius of the circle.  (I put `%` in front of the command in the code.)  Why isn't it being drawn?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections}



\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

%E' is a point on the ray from D through E. These commands draw edges $DF$ and
%$E'F$ so that $\angle{\mathit{E'DF}} = 30$. $DF$ is to be drawn at an angle
%120 degrees and DE' is to be drawn at an angle of 150 degrees.
\coordinate (D) at (0,0);
\node (vertex_D) at ($(D) + (-45:7.5pt)$){$D$};
\coordinate (F) at (120:6);
\node (vertex_F) at ($(F) + (90:7.5pt)$){$F$};
\coordinate (E') at (150:9);
\node (vertex_E') at ($(E') + (-90:7.5pt)$){};
\draw (D) -- (F);
\draw[name path=DE'] (D) -- (E');

\path pic[draw, angle radius=10mm,"$30$",angle eccentricity=1.25] {angle = F--D--E'};

%These commands label the length of DF.
\coordinate (DF_midpoint) at ($(D)!0.5!(F)$);
\node (DF_midpoint_label) at ($(DF_midpoint) + (30:7.5pt)$) {8};


%These commands draw the height of the triangle from F to line segment $DE'$.
%The height is labeled $h$.
\coordinate (P) at ($(D)!(F)!(E')$);
\draw [dashed] (F) -- (P) node [midway,above left]{$4$};
\node (point_P) at ($(P) + (-120:7.5pt)$){$P$};


%These commands draw an arc of a circle centered at F with radius 5.
\draw[dashed,draw=blue!30,name path=arc] (F) ++(150:3.75) arc (150:290:3.75);
%\draw[dashed,draw=blue!30] (F) -- (F) ++(225:3.75) node [midway,above left]{$5$};


%The following commands make the right-angle mark.
\coordinate (U) at ($(P)!4mm!45:(D)$);
\draw (U) -- ($(P)!(U)!(D)$);
\draw (U) -- ($(P)!(U)!(F)$);

%These commands label the intersections of the arc with line segment DE'
%intersection-1 and intersection-2.
\draw[name intersections={of= arc and DE'}];

%These commands draw line segments from $F$ to the two intersections on
%line segment DE'.

\draw[red] (F) -- (intersection-1);
\draw[blue] (F) -- (intersection-2);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You are drawing a line from (F) to (F) then moving to ++(etc.)  See Oberdiek's solution.  You could also use (F) ++(etc.) -- (F).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\tikzlibrary{quotes}` is missing and probably you want something like

```
\draw[dashed,draw=blue!30] (F) -- ($(F) +(225:3.75)$) node [midway,above left]{$5$};
```

Comment: I did try using the `calc` package by specifying the coordinate `($(F) ++(225:3.75)$)`.  (This is not in my post.)  I got an error. The only difference between this code and your code is that I used `++` and you used `+`.